# DNS Server in C to return IP Address and port number

Tags: c, visual-studio, dns

From my understanding of a DNS Server, a simple explanation is that for a given hostname the DNS server uses a lookup table to return the IP Address of the hostname.

For one of my projects, I used to connect my client to the server through a wifi network, and specify the IP Address and port at which the server is listening on the client.
A new requirement has come which asks to specify a DNS server in the network settings, and the DNS server in turn returns the IP Address and port number of my server.

I went through online to check the request/ response to A DNS server, and I found many places it is mentioned that port number is not sent by the DNS Server. Is it right?

I have coded my project in Visual studio 2005. Is there any libray/code of a DNS Server which I can integrate with my existing visual studio project? And is it possible, that for a particular host name I can specify the port number in the response?

I have checked many source codes for DNS Server in C like ldns/ bind ,  but I have not found a way to integrate with visual studio.

Comment: DNS server can be specified in the DHCP response, similarly you could use multicast DNS - mDNS that would not require a server setting at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an additional information about given domain in TXT DNS record. So, you could add text tag:value part into your domain TXT record.

Comment: Where do I set? Which library should I use? And is it possible to integrate with visual studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Might this be what user is trying to define? [DNS SRV record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record)

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. Is there any C library which implements that and can be integrated with visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know any off the top of my head. Try searching for libraries that support RFC2782.

It is not completely clear to me from your question if you want a server(ansering SRV requests) or client (looking up SRV records) implementation. I would think that at least the client side is implemented in some librariest supporting other DNS lookups.

Comment: I need the server side implementation.

Comment: BIND 10 mentions this feature in some [developement version release notes](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00439/0/BIND-10-devel-20110819-Release-Notes.html)

Comment: I checked it out, but problem is like with most other libraries,I cannot find a version which I can link with visual studio. That is really important

Answer (score 0):

That just doesn't make sense, the port is not part of the host's domain name. A given host (=a single domain name) can run any number of applications, i.e. have any number of ports open.

Your idea would require that some form of identity of the desired application was sent to the DNS server for the the look-up, or that it could reply with a list of running services and their ports. It just doesn't work like that, at least as far as I know.

There's nothing stopping you from running a web server (normally on port 80) on any other port, such as 8080 as is often done during development. The URL will then be `http://example.com:8080`, and since the browser only looks up the `example.com` part in DNS there's no way for the DNS to override the port number.

Comment: Yes, when I was testing without a DNS Server, I used to specify in the format http://ipaddress/example:8080 or https://ipaddress/example:443 But now is it possible that if I run a DNS Server in my machine and the client sends a request, in this way http://xyz.com/example, the DNS server return ipaddress and port 8080?

Comment: @user you'll have to modify the DNS code to do that - or use another field, like txt to specify the port - and modify also the browsers code if you want something automatic ; but you probably don't need that. The port is agreed between the participants - the most common is 80 (http) or 443 (https) and the browsers addresses them by default  without you doing anything (at times, maybe for https). So if you use port 12345 on your web server, all participants have to make a bookmark `myserver.org:12345`